# IPhone Cv Attachments

Tags: iphone, email

Sometime I get email from recruiters asking for my cv in word format.  I tend to have the cv saved in my hotmail email account as an email attachment.  How can I reply back to these recruiters and add my word cv in the same reply email.  Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can save your cv in iCloud Drive, and then attach it.
Start writing an email on your phone, long press the text area, press the right arrow till you can see an add attachments button.

You can upload to iCloud Drive from finder on a Mac, save to iCloud Drive on iOS, or use iCloud.com on Windows.

[Apple support about iCloud Drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201104)